# How to search and sort a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sorting, 2d

We are doing a program in class to read in about 100 lines of code, store it, and sort it. The code is first an employee's ID number followed by their sales. There are only 12 employees. We have to store it in a 12x4 2D array. We have to have the employee number, the total number of sales they made (counter), their total sales amount, and the average of all their sales/count.

My issue is figuring out how to write a search function that is not already in the library. He mentioned returning the subscript from the search function to associate that ID number with a subscript. We can only use user-created functions and 2d arrays. Have not learned pointers or vectors yet.

So far I have done the bare bones b/c I'm not sure how to continue reading 100 values, but condensing them down to 12 people. Could someone please help demonstrate how to begin sorting this 2D array? Please be as verbose as possible as this is only my 2nd semester. I apologies if I have not explained it properly.

```cpp
// example of data in file. ID number on left and a sale made on right. 
-322 10.80
-848 920.00
-828 1267.00
-848 8320.00
-229 66330.00

// the bubble sort we have to use 
void sort(float sales[], int size) 
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {
            //checking if previous value is
            //grater than next one or not
            if(sales[j] > sales[j+1]) {
                float temp = sales[j];
                sales[j] = sales[j+1];
                sales[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

// completely stuck here 
int search_ID(float sales[][4])  
{
    int r;
    for(c = 0; c <= 0; c++) {
        for(r = 0; r < 13; r++) {
            if(sales[r][c] != sales[r][c]) {
                //was thinking of if the ID number 
                //matches or doesn't match perform a t/F
            }
        }
    }
    return sub;
}

// the avg sales for each employee
float avgSale(float sales[][4], int rowNum) 
{
    int r, c, totalSales;
    float avg;

    // would just use a for loop in main to call each row num. 
    for(r = rowNum; r <= rowNum; r++) {
        for (c = 3; c < 4; c++) {
            avg=sales[r][c]/totalSales;
        }
    }
    return avg;
}

// we have to print a report with ID, Num sales, total sales, and avg for 
// each so the 4 columns 
void printReport(float sales[][4]) 
{
    int r, c;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

    for(r = 0; r < 13; r++) {
        for(c = 0; c <= 1; c++) {
            cout << sales[r][c] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    infile.open("C://data//input//Sales.txt");
    outfile.open("C:\\data\\SalesmenReport.txt");

    //check if file opens 
    if(!infile) {
        cout << "File did not open. Please try again."<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int size=12; 
    int sub;
    float avg;
    float sales[size][4];
    int r, c, sub;

    for(r = 0; r < 13; r++) {
        for(c=0;c<=1;c++) {
            infile >> sales[r][c];
            // he showed us this as an example to call the search, idk where 
            // to put it or what to put in it. 
            sub = search_ID(sales); 
        }
    }

    printReport(sales);
    avg = avgSale(sales, 0);
```

**Edit & Run**

I expect when the program is completed to be able to print the 12 employee ID numbers, their number of sales, total amount each salesman made, and each person's average clear across left to right in a table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass empId (to be searched) as a parameter to the function. For example, following function will return 1 if it finds the record with given employee id, otherwise 0.

```
int search_ID(float sales[][4], int empIdToBeSearched)  
{
    int r, found;
    found = 0;
        for(r = 0; r < 13; r++) {
            if(sales[r][0] == empIdToBeSearched) {
              found = 1;
              break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

And while sorting the records you should apply the sorting algorithm on any column that you want **but while swapping the data you should swap the entire row and not just the particular cell**. So in this case your temp (used in sort function) should be 2-D array something like `float temp[1][4]`.

Comment: What needs to be written on the function call when I do the search_ID function? What is the purpose of returning 1? I have to be able to call this function every time a number is read in to make sure the number is/is not a duplicate and if it is, add the sums in col 2 to the sums previously written in column 2. If it is not a duplicate, I need to skip a row and add the new number in.  On the function call for the value empIdToBeSearched, does that need to be r for row since I don't know if the next value is a duplicate or not?